# Use completableFuture to write doGET response from doPOST

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I have 2 APIs (doGET and doPOST) and I am trying to use an async mechanism to make doPOST write `httpServletResponse` for doGET request.

[image]

My control flow -

1. Client make a requestA (getData) call
2. Java server does some processing and makes a call to out of environment 3rd party API
3. 3rd party API does not return response but calls my another endpoint doPOST
4. doPOST now need to write an object of httpServletResponse into doGET
5. doGET returns this object as soon as doPOST is done.

To solve this problem, I figured out I can use some asynchronous programming mechanism like `CompletableFuture` in java. But I am confused about how to exactly set this mechanism in my code. Here is what I have done so far -

**doGET**

```
public void doGET(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // some processing
    // Call 3rd Party API
    CompletableFuture<HttpServletRequest> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doPOST());
    while (!completableFuture.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("CompletableFuture is not finished yet...");
    }
    HttpServletRequest result = completableFuture.get();
    
    response = result;
}
```

I have not been able to figure out how can I set up completableFuture for this. Need help here.

**doPOST**

```
public HttpServletResponse doPOST(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // receive 3rd party request 
    // add data from 3rd party request into a new response object 
    // add response object into hashmap
}
```

How can I properly make this work?

Comment: do you need response from 3rd Party Api in doPost?

Comment: I'm not sure you really want to print "CompletableFuture is not finished yet" in loop, that would make the JVM print potentially thousands of time the same message with no utility at all. Instead, just call .get() which will wait for the Future to be complete before to resume execution.

Comment: if sequence of execution of steps are dependent on each other then there is not benefit of  using completable future. But if there are some steps that are not dependent on each other, you can get the benefit of using completable future.

Comment: @Pirate 3rd party API request is a POST request. So I only need to send 200 OK to that request and then doPOST will perform write of doGET response.

Comment: @AniruddhaTekade 3rd party API request is POST request, it doesn't matter. My question is do you need response from 3rd party API before doPost?

Comment: @Pirate thank you for the clarification. No, 3rd party API do not respond back to my request. 3rd party API call from doGET is also post request. It only sends a 200 OK. doPOST will then write an actual response for doGET.

Comment: @AniruddhaTekade, what happen if 3rd party API doesn't respond 200?

Comment: I think the request will fail. Since I am working on MVP. I have not developed my thoughts into it yet. But I think those cases can then be taken care of. Have kept it as future work once the basic workflow is completed.

Comment: See your doPost is dependent on 3rd party response. Here response means not only response body, also status code returned by api. In such cases, both apis are dependent on each other, so you will not be getting any benefit of using completable future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a map of request ids vs. an object as property of your class exposing the two methods:

```
private final Map<String, HttpRequestResponse> requests = new HashMap<>();
```

... where the class `HttpRequestResponse` is a simple wrapper for a request (that you receive upon `doGET`) and a response (that will be supplied by `doPOST)`:

```
class HttpRequestResponse {
    private final HttpServletRequest request;
    private final CompletableFuture<HttpServletResponse> responseSupplier;

    public HttpRequestResponse(HttpServletRequest request, CompletableFuture<HttpServletResponse> responseSupplier) {
        this.request = request;
        this.responseSupplier = responseSupplier;
    }

    public void supplyResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.responseSupplier.complete(response); //<-- this will release the .get()
    }

    //getters
    public CompletableFuture<HttpServletResponse> getSupplier() {
        return responseSupplier;
    }
}
```

Upon receiving the request on `doGET`, you will create the instance and put it into the map, then wait for the result:

```
public void doGET(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpRequestResponse responseSupplier = new HttpRequestResponse(request, new CompletableFuture<>());
    requests.put(yourId, responseSupplier); //add supplier to the map (so that doPOST can retrieve it later)
    //perform request to your 3rd party API
    response = responseSupplier.getSupplier().get(); //<- wait until someone completes the future
}
```

On the other hand, upon receiving the response from the 3rd party API on `doPOST`, you will need to get the future by its id, remove it from the map and complete it:

```
public void doPOST(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpRequestResponse responseSupplier = requests.remove(yourId); //<-- removes the supplier from the map and returns it to you
    responseSupplier.getSupplier().complete(<your response>); //<-- once you complete the future with a result, the .get() which is hanging on doGET will return
}
```

---

Question: why do you want to use asynchronous pattern if the `doGET` waits anyway for the response to be ready before continuing?
I guess once you put this in place, the `doGET` can become asynchronous as well and return the execution id (which the client can then listen for a result).

Comment: I am trying to reproduce a mechanism that AWS perform for object lambda. This is my personal project. In AWS, there is an API called WriteGetObjectResponse() which writes response into GetObject() and then getObject() returns it. I am trying to figure out how they might have done it.

Comment: my 3rd party API is a post request. So I only need to send 200 OK to 3rd party API as status code and perform the building of response for my original request. I am going to try your solution now.

Comment: I think your answer is the one that I am looking for. But I am confused on doPOST part a little bit. `responseSupplier.getSupplier().complete(<your response>);` you have mentioned `<your-response>`. So if I am willing to build a response to doGET request, should I first build a response object and then provide it in theplace of `<your-response>`?

Comment: @AniruddhaTekade the <your-response> should just contain whatever you were using in your previous solution to write a response for your doGET

Comment: Ok. Then I need to build a doGETResponse and add pass to `.complete()` so that I can get it in doGET() method. Is there any efficient way to build httpServletResponse() ?

Comment: @a13e I'm not sure about it, I'm not really acquainted to these objects. I just showed you how to use anything inside a Completable Future, but I thought you were already building this object on your own..

Comment: if the data to be returned from doGET (which means being written from doPOST) is too big, can we have completableFuture setup with a streaming mechanism? I mean start sending data to user as doPOST receive it.

Comment: @a13e it is surely possible but it's a completely different question. I would suggest you close this thread and open a new one targeting the right question, you will get more attention from a larger audience and we avoid extending too much the discussion on an unrelated post :)

Comment: I have posted my question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546915/make-streaming-response-while-using-completablefuture