# Make streaming response body while using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, streaming, completable-future

I have setup a following mechanism which uses an async setup with the help of CompletableFuture. doGET is blocked while waiting for doPOST operation to complete.

[image]

**Class level hashmap**

```
private final Map<String, HttpRequestResponse> requests = new HashMap<>();
```

**HttpRequestResponse Wrapper class**

```
public class HttpRequestResponse {
private final HttpServletRequest request;
private final CompletableFuture<HttpServletResponse> responseSupplier;

public HttpRequestResponse(HttpServletRequest request, CompletableFuture<HttpServletResponse> responseSupplier) {
    this.request = request;
    this.responseSupplier = responseSupplier;
}

public void supplyResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
    this.responseSupplier.complete(response); //<-- this will release the .get()
}

//getters
public CompletableFuture<HttpServletResponse> getSupplier() {
    return responseSupplier;
}
```

}

**doGET**

```
public void doGET(Request jettyReq, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    // 1. Read request ID for the request
    String xRequestId = request.getHeader("X-Request-ID");

    // 2. Upon receiving the request, create the instance of wrapper
    //    and put it into the map, then wait for the result
    HttpRequestResponse responseSupplier = new HttpRequestResponse(request, new CompletableFuture<>());
    requests.put(xRequestId, responseSupplier); //add supplier to the map (so that doPOST can retrieve it later)

    // perform other processing & perform request to 3rd party server

    try {
        response = responseSupplier.getSupplier().get(); //<- wait until someone completes the future
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So here `.get()` method is a blocking call which is waiting till 3rd party API call made to doPOST is processed completely. As soon as doPOST is done writing a response to the request of doGET, doGET can simply return it.

**doPOST**

```
public void  doPOST(Request jettyReq, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
    // upon receiving the response from the 3rd party API on writeGetObjectResponse,
    // I will need to get the future by its id, remove it from the map and complete it:
    String xRequestId = request.getHeader("X-Request-ID");
    HttpRequestResponse responseSupplier = requests.remove(xRequestId); // removes the supplier from the map and returns it to you

    // Build a complete response
    HttpServletResponse getObjectResponse = response;

    // set response headers
    getObjectResponse.setContentType("application/json");
    getObjectResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    // write payload into response body
    String payloadRequest = null;
    try {
        payloadRequest = getBody(request);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = getObjectResponse.getWriter();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.print(payloadRequest);
    out.flush();

    // complete the future so that getObject() can access it.
    responseSupplier.getSupplier().complete(getObjectResponse);

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

The response object I am trying to build can have a large amount of data to return. I am in search of a mechanism where I can **perform a streaming return of data or response body**. How do I solve this issue?